# MySQL - How to order by two columns consecutively?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this simple query that orders the products on my web application in descending order, based on the price/discount.

The problem is that I want to order items by the discount first, and *then* order items by the cost. At the moment it's jumbling the two together.

Here's my PHP:

```
$products = DB::fetch("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `products` ORDER BY discount DESC, cost DESC");
```

Comment: Your query should be ordering by the discount first and then the cost.  You could be running a different query, you could be misinterpreting the results, or the data may not be what you expect.  Sample data and the results you are getting might help explain the problem.

Comment: Ars discount and cost numeric fields?

Comment: Yes they are numeric fields

Comment: I'm differently not running more than one query or misinterpreting the results. I also didn't

Comment: _“Here's my PHP:”_ – take your query, and execute it using a frontend such as phpMyAdmin or similar. Then you’ll see whether the results are ordered correctly or not.

Answer (score 1):

It seem by your query that you're paginating results (before executing the query posted in the question).

In that case you have to sort with the desired ordering **before** you paginate.

Otherwise you'll get a page with randomly sorted items and then you'll sort just that page not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `products` ORDER BY discount,cost DESC
```

That's all

Comment: what is SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ?

Comment: I'm using pagination, so it limits the result set to the current page. I left out the rest of that code because it's irrelevant to the question and doesn't conflict with it

Comment: how do you perform limit here before * ? why limits are not at the end?

Comment: Right after it I have '$total = DB::fetch("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total");'